# Verifying iOS app owernship

Tags: ios, web-services, authentication, verification

I am building a web application for iOS app developers. Once a user signs up, they have the option to add their iOS app to my platform.

What I need to do is verify that they are in fact the owner of the app. For example: I don't want anyone to sign up and claim they own Uber when they don't.

Question: How can I verify iOS app ownership? Is there a REST/SOAP API in existence for this need?

Comment: What are you doing that it'd matter? What secret data do I get if I put in Uber as mine?

Comment: Once an app is claimed no one else can claim it. If the owner of uber signed up they wouldn't be able to add their own app. Thats bad.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method of verifying this.